# When i compile with xelatex i get an error. Troubles with font Times New Roman

Tags: macos, fonts, latex, tex, xelatex

macOS Mojave. MacTex installed.

```
lid filename `[lmroman10-regular]', contains '['

! Font TU/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text; at 10.0pt not loadab
le: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.54 \normalsize
```

This error

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

Add this package with this line

```
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
```

Set with this line

Comment: ```sudo tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended``` does not fix this problem

Comment: Can you make a [mre] and show the .log file of it?

Comment: I've had the same problem.  The workaround I did was to use STIXgeneral font as it is very similar looking to Times New Roman.

Answer (score 0):

Writing in TeXShop fixed my problem. Also i do `sudo tlmgr install scheme-full`.